# Firefox extension not working with URLs other than http:// https://

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, xpi

I have installed two Firefox Extensions to translate words when I double click on them: [Google Translator](https://addons.mozilla.org/En-us/firefox/addon/google-translator/?src=search) and [Wictionary and Google Translate](https://addons.mozilla.org/En-us/firefox/addon/google-dictionary-and-google-t/).

Both offer you the possibility to translate words just by double clicking on them. But the difference is, Wictionary and Google Translate just works everywhere i double click. It works with local files (file:///...) ,EPUBReader extension which opens EPUB files inside Firefox with a URL something like (about:epubreader?id=5) etc. Since I prefer Google Translator, I want to use it the same way I can use Wictionary and Google Translate, but it doesn't work with any URL other than http:// https:// .

I have tried to compare their source codes and searched several times to find and edit this functionality in Google Translator, but could not do anything.

Help anyone??
Thanks

Some directory from Google Translator

- resources:

  - igtranslator:

    - lib:

      - firefox.js
      - common.js
      - config.js
    - data:

      - (many png, html, css)
      - inject.js
      - options.js
      - popup.js
- bootstrap.js

Comment: are their source codes using Firefox's sdk?

Comment: @winhowes sorry for being noobish but i am new to this thing.. still after doing some research i think i understand what you mean after reading this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Guides/SDK_vs_XUL article. Wictionary addon has many XUL files and a typical XUL structure with skin, content and locale folders. It also needs to be restarted after installing it. Google Translator has only one XUL file and requires no restart. It also has an addon-sdk folder somewhere, although empty. Wictionary does not have such a folder.

Comment: gotcha, well without having gone through their code, I would look for regex in their code that indicates what url protocols they are listening for

Comment: can you give me a tip where to look for? i have posted some important directory files

Comment: Yeah, it should be in the lib files. Probably in firefox.js and possibly in some object called PageMod

Comment: ok so this is the line pageMod  = require("sdk/page-mod")

Comment: Yep look down that file for a line like this: `pageMod.PageMod({
  include:` whatever comes next will tell you what pages it's running on

Comment: please have a look below, i posted it in an answer

Comment: @winhowes first of all thanks a lot, changing the include line like this include: [" * ","file://*","about:*"] will do the trick for local files. But URLs that start with "about:", like this EPUBReader URL, about:epubreader?id=5 still won't work. I don't understand why?? I need to find a way to solve this, so that i can be able to use the addon on the EPUBReader extension.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code snippet from firefox.js that is responsible for listening to the URL protocols:

```
var workers = [], content_script_arr = [];
    pageMod.PageMod({ /* page */
      include: ["*"],
      contentScriptFile: [data.url("content_script/inject.js")],
      contentScriptWhen: "start",
      contentStyleFile : data.url("content_script/inject.css"),
      onAttach: function(worker) {
        array.add(workers, worker);
        worker.on('pageshow', function() { array.add(workers, this); });
        worker.on('pagehide', function() { array.remove(workers, this); });
        worker.on('detach', function() { array.remove(workers, this); });
        content_script_arr.forEach(function (arr) {
          worker.port.on(arr[0], arr[1]);
        });
      }
    });
```

Changing the `include:` line to

```
 include: ["*","file://*"],
```

will do the trick for local files.